# como eliminar un valor en concreto del path desde cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd

este es el valor de mi variable de entorno PATH en windows 10.

PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\AutoFirma\AutoFirma;c:\ora18;C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\usuario.dotnet\tools

Alguien me podria decir como eliminar unicamente el valor "c:\ora18" de mi variable path desde el cmd de windows?

Answer (score 0):

Un usuario muy amable de otro foro me ha dado esta respuesta que me ha funcionado perfectamente. Lo pongo por aqui por si a alguien pudiera servirle de utilidad. El comando seria el siguiente:
set PATH=%PATH:;c:\ora18;=;%